# C# Dynamic Data Linq To SQL website assembly loading

Tags: c#, assembly-loading

I am using visual studio 2010 ultimate. I have got the following error when I try to import a dynamic data linq to sql website project on my computer:

> ------ Rebuild All started: Project: C:...\TestVersion99Website\, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ Validating Web Site Building
>   directory '/TestVersion99Website/App_Code/'. Building directory
>   '/TestVersion99Website/DynamicData/Content/'. Building directory
>   '/TestVersion99Website/DynamicData/FieldTemplates/'.
>   C:\Users\Test\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\WebSites\TestVersion99Website\DynamicData\FieldTemplates\MultilineText_Edit.ascx(7):
>   Build (web): Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.DynamicData,
>   Version=99.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   ... C:\Users\Test\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\WebSites\TestVersion99Website\DynamicData\FieldTemplates\Text_Edit.ascx(7):
>   Build (web): Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.DynamicData,
>   Version=99.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Validation Complete
>   ========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

The website was written using .net 3.5 sp1 framework. The System.Web.DynamicData assembly was from DynamicData 4 preview project from codeplex.

To identify the error, I have created a new dynamic data linq to sql website project using .net 3.5 framework. Once the website is built, I removed the reference to "System.Web.Dynamicdata 3.5.0.0". I created a new Bin folder, and copied the assembly "Microsoft.Web.Extensions 99.0.0.0, System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations 99.0.0.0, System.Web.DynamicData 99.0.0.0" into the Bin folder. I then made sure that in web.config the assembly versions are changed to 99.0.0.0. However, When I tried to build the solution, I still had the same error messages. I have no idea why this is happening and am really really very frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

Check for any bindingRedirect you have in your web.config.

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.DynamicData"   publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.5.0.0" newVersion="99.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```